# How to select the last value from the Dropdown without Select tag through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropdown, webdriverwait

I am new to automating using Selenium.
I was trying to select the last element in the drop-down that shows the number of (stock) rows on the page on yahoo finance web-page. 
When I inspect the HTML I do not see any select tags and hence I cannot search for options in the dropdown. Also I am not sure how to search for the XPATH or elements after clicking the down arrow as it is not present in the page source.

Below is the code that I am working on. I am able to click the dropdown but am stuck on the next steps to click on the last option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


webDriver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10)

webDriver.maximize_window()
webDriver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/sector/technology")

xpath = "//div[@data-test='select-container']"
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
webDriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

The HTML snippet that I was able to extract is as follows:

```
<div class="W(100%) Mt(15px) Ta(end)" data-reactid="1375">
   <span class="Pos(r) Mend(20px) Va(m)" data-reactid="1376">
      <div class="O(n):f O(n):h P(0) M(0) Cur(p):h D(ib)" tabindex="0" data-test="select-container" data-reactid="1377">
         <span data-test="showRows-select-selected" class="O(n):f O(n):h P(0) M(0) C($c-fuji-blue-1-b) Fz(s) Fw(500)" data-reactid="1378"><span data-reactid="1379">Show 50 rows</span></span>
         <svg class="H(8px) W(8px) Va(m)! Mstart(8px) Stk($c-fuji-blue-1-b)! Fill($c-fuji-blue-1-b)! Cur(p)" width="8" style="fill:#000;stroke:#000;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;" height="8" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-icon="CoreArrowDown" data-reactid="1380">
            <path d="M500.77 131.432L477.53 108.18c-14.45-14.55-40.11-14.55-54.51 0L255.845 275.363 88.582 108.124c-15.015-14.874-39.363-14.874-54.42.108L10.94 131.486c-14.58 14.44-14.58 40.11-.033 54.442l217.77 217.845c15.004 14.82 39.33 14.874 54.42-.108L500.88 185.82c14.818-14.982 14.87-39.298-.11-54.388z" data-reactid="1381"></path>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </span>
   <button class="Va(m) Bd(0) M(0) P(0) Mend(10px) O(n):f C($gray)" disabled="" data-reactid="1382">
      <svg class="Va(m)! Fill($gray)! Stk($gray)! Cur(a)! Cur(p)" width="18" style="fill:#000;stroke:#000;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;" height="18" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-icon="double-left" data-reactid="1383">
         <path d="M14.605 23.995l9.813-9.813c.755-.757.767-2.023-.006-2.795-.78-.78-2.027-.777-2.795-.006L9 23.996l12.62 12.62c.757.756 2.023.767 2.796-.007.78-.78.777-2.025.006-2.796l-9.817-9.817zM26.605 23.995l9.813-9.813c.755-.757.767-2.023-.006-2.795-.78-.78-2.027-.777-2.795-.006L21 23.996l12.62 12.62c.757.756 2.023.767 2.796-.007.78-.78.777-2.025.006-2.796l-9.817-9.817z" data-reactid="1384"></path>
      </svg>
   </button>
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the last element in the drop-down that shows the number of (stock) rows on the page on [finance.yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/sector/technology) web-page you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  webDriver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  webDriver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/sector/technology")
  WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-test='showRows-select-selected']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test='showRows-select-menu']//*[contains(., 'Show 100 rows')]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: count100]

Answer (score 0):

Without clicking, if you want to traverse all elements. then

Get this following text. It shows it contains 466 results.

> 401-466 of 466 results

So your first url would be

```
?offset=0&count=100
```

second would be

```
?offset=100&count=100
```

Third

```
?offset=200&count=100
```

fourth

```
?offset=300&count=100
```

and final

```
?offset=400&count=100
```

You can do the math.

However, if you want to click on dropdown option, then.

```
xpath = "//div[@data-test='select-container']"
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
webDriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

After this and new `div` element is being added which has `span` for your options. The html code you shared, it's not related.

```
<div class="Pt(5px) Pb(5px) Pos(a) End(0px) Z(10) Bgc(#fff) Bd Bdc($c-fuji-grey-c) Bdrs(2px) Bxsh($boxShadow) Whs(nw)" data-test="showRows-select-menu">
    <div class="Ta(start) Px(20px) Py(10px) Cur(p) Bgc($pillBgBlue):h Fz(s)" data-value="25">
        <span>Show 25 rows</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Ta(start) Px(20px) Py(10px) Cur(p) Bgc($pillBgBlue):h Fz(s)" data-value="50">
        <span>Show 50 rows</span>
    </div>

    <div class="Ta(start) Px(20px) Py(10px) Cur(p) Bgc($pillBgBlue):h Fz(s) Fw(b)" data-value="100">
    <span>Show 100 rows</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what you need to do is, after you click on `link` you need to wait until this element is added to your html.

```
xpath = "//div[@data-test='showRows-select-menu']"
elem = wait.until(EC. presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
total_dropdown = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-test='showRows-select-menu']/div")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-test='showRows-select-menu']/div[total_dropdown+1]/span").click()
```

I haven't tested the code, However I think you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks Gaurang. I want to automate going to each page. Hence I am not sure if I can customize the url to show 100 rows each time.

Comment: Secondly, how can I know if the drop down has 100 rows. I mean what if the last option in the drop down is 50 rows? Is there another way where I can select last value without hard coding it? Thanks again